# Closing three forms form button

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

in form1

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Form Form4 = new Form4();
      Form Form5 = new Form5();
      Form Form6 = new Form6();
      Form4.Show();
      Form5.Show();
      Form6.Show();
 }
```

in *form5* i have a button that must close form4, form5 and form6. as following:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form Form4 = new Form4();
                Form Form6 = new Form6();
                Form4.Close();
                Form6.Close();
                this.Close();
            }
```

but `Form4` and `Form6` are still open!!!

Comment: in `button2_Click` you create new forms and then close them. Forms created in `button6_Click` are different and still open. In `button2_Click` you need obtain somehow references to forms created in `button6_Click` and close them

Comment: to do what you want you should make all your forms globaly or pass reference forms what you need close to form which will close them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form4 form4 = (Form4) Application.OpenForms["Form4"];                
            Form5 form5 = (Form5) Application.OpenForms["Form5"];                
            form4.Close();
            form5.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

To close in proper way you have to know what do you want to close. In your case you are creating new Forms on beggining, and another ones with the same names visible locally before trying to destroy them.

Form Form6 = new Form6(); are totally different in both of your clicked buttons. Then, if you want to make it more visible generate interesting forms in constructor method and put definition as class fields like.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form form2;  // be sure all componentes see all forms
    Form form3;
    Form form4;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form2 = new Form();  // create new Forms
        form3 = new Form();

        var button = new Button();  
        button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click); // tell the button what should be called when click

        form4 = new Form();  
        form4.Controls.Add(button);  // add button progrimicaly to form
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Hide();  // hide on click
        form3.Hide();
        form4.Hide();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2.Show();   // show on load
        form3.Show();
        form4.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case? Nothing, it is just event handler added to button which I didn't see was added in user's code. Please see that user is using _Form_ not overriden _Form1_ etc - I assume it is standard class.